# Change of order of integration

Tags: integration

Can anyone please help me in identifying the change of order in the following integration $$\int\limits_0^\infty  {\int\limits_{\frac{{t - z}}{h}}^\infty  {f\left( {h,t,u,z} \right)du \,dz} }, $$ if I substitute for $v={\frac{{t - z}}{h}},$ where $f()$ is any function, $0\le t \le \infty$ and $h\ge 0$.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From drawing a picture of the region in question, swapping the order of integration gives two integrals

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{t}{h}} \int_{t-hu}^\infty \cdots + \int_{\frac{t}{h}}^\infty \int_0^\infty \cdots$$

Or more consicsely

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{\max\left(t-hu,0\right)}^\infty \cdots$$

Comment: Thanks. Suppose I am adding an additional condition that $Z \ge t$ always.Whether this will have an effect on the order?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I come up with to the best of my abilities:

Note that in order to be able to change the order of integration, Fubini-Tonelli's Theorem requires the existence of $\int \int |f|$  in the first place. If that integral is not finite, it does not exist and a change of order of integration is not generally allowed.

Assuming it exists, you are looking to map $\{(z,u) \mid u=\frac{t-z}{h}, z\in [0,\infty) \}$ to $\{(u,z) \mid z=t-hu, u\in (-\infty,\frac{t}{h}) \} \cup \{(u,z) \mid z\in[0,\infty), u\in [\frac{t}{h},\infty) \}$.

Thus change of order of integration entails that $\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{\frac{t-z}{h}}^{\infty}f dudz $ becomes $\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{t}{h}} \int_{t-hu}^{\infty}f dzdu + \int_{\frac{t}{h}}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty}f dzdu $.

How to arrive at this? The boring (and incomplete) answer, solve the initial inner lower limit for z (inverse function). The more intuitive answer: consider the set of points that is created by letting $z$ go from $0$ to $\infty$ and for each value of $z$ you you consider all values of $u$ such that $u \geq \frac{t-z}{h}$. You end up with the section above the graph of the function $u(z)=\frac{t-z}{h}$. This equates to the domain of integration in the initial problem.

Now reverse the interpretation and look at the set created by letting $u$ go from $-\infty$ to $\frac{t}{h}$, which is the image of $\left.u(z)\right|_{[0,\infty)}$. To arrive at the same set of points as before you want to consider the same graph, but in terms of $u$ instead of $z$. This leads to the function $z(u)=t-hu$ which satisfies i) $z(0)=t$ and ii) $z(\frac{t}{h})=0$. We just created the same linear function with inversion of variables. Obviously this is the inverse. However, this is not quite the full picture. We still lack the points for which $u\geq \frac{t}{h} \land z\geq 0$, which leads to the second integral.

You can see this most clearly by actually drawing the graphs, which I strongly suggest, because putting it into words can only do so much while seeing it visually is almost self-explanatory.

(Edit: I added the second integral which I realized my answer was missing after seeing Ninad Munshi's correct answer)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Suppose I am adding an additional condition that $Z \ge t$ always.Whether this will have an effect on the order?